# How can the "you cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig bundle is not available" error in symfony 6 be debugged?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony6

I just recently upgraded my project from symfony 4 to 6, without much problems. The current online version is using symfony6 without problem.

I am now trying to clean the code, removing some useless parts and other little modifications, and I just met a strange problem. All my pages are now giving me the error:

> You cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig Bundle is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle".

Problem is: the package is present, so the recommended command does nothing.

I tried to check the code triggering the exception:

```
   protected function renderView(string $view, array $parameters = []): string
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('twig')) {
            throw new \LogicException('You cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig Bundle is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle".');
        }


    ...
    }
```

So I checked the twig service with `bin/console debug:container twig`, which gives me the same output as with the current working version.

There is a note:

> "! [NOTE] The "twig" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled."

But this note is also present in my production code without problem.

I brought no real modification to the controller files between the two versions, the main difference being files moved and namespaces adapted to this change.

I don't have any ideas other than doing all these changes all over again, but I fear I'll fall on the same result.

Edit:

The problem look larger that I thought, as I get the same problem with the security bundle.

I tried to inject `\Twig\Environment` in the controller method, and it autowired with no problems.

I tried to update all the recipes with `composer recipes`, with no interesting result.

I tried to compare it to a newly created Symfony6 controller with twig, but found no significant differences, except the use of php attributes, which I tried to use in my project, with no result either.

Result of `bin/console debug:container HomeController`:

```
Option             Value 
----------------- -------------------------------
Service ID         App\Controller\HomeController 
Class              App\Controller\HomeController 
Tags               controller.service_arguments 
                   container.service_subscriber 
Calls              setContainer 
Public             yes 
Synthetic          no 
Lazy               no 
Shared             yes 
Abstract           no 
Autowired          yes 
Autoconfigured     yes
Usages             none
```

Edit:

To be honest, if twig is now a private service, not accessible through the container, why is the [AbstractController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php) still using this line:

```
        if (!$this->container->has('twig')) {
            throw new \LogicException('You cannot use the "renderView" method if the Twig Bundle is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle".');
        }
```

Wouldn't that just cause an error for everyone ? Then why not, and only now for me while it doesn't for my current version (my production is operational with the same Symfony 6 packages)

Edit:

By playing in the vendors, I managed to find that in my original code, the `ServiceLocator` is used in the `AbstractController`, but in my bugged one, it seems to be a cached `Container` class that is used (as `$this->container`).

So the `has()` method called in not the same...

Comment: Seems strange.  I assume you tried to rebuild the cache.  This is happening inside of your controllers which extend AbstractController?  And AbstractController::getSubscribedServices() has an entry for twig?  And your controllers are autowired?

Comment: I did try clearing the cache, even dropping the folder completely. 
I tried to dump the AbstractController::getSubscribedServices(), and there is a ["twig" => "?Twig\Environment"] part. My controller are correctly autowired, other services doesn't trigger any problems. It's as if the Container::has() method had an error.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to go into the Container class, edit the Container::has() method, to dump some data, and it seems the container doesn't know the "twig" service in this call, but I don't get why, he does display it in the "debug:container" cli

Comment: Ok, my problem is larger than that, I just saw that I can also get the "The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle"." error on an AbstractController::denyAccessUnlessGranted() call.

Comment: I suppose you could double check that config/bundles.php has all you bundles listed.  And maybe run `bin/console debug:container SomeController` and verify that setContainer is being called as well as having the `container.service_subscriber` tag.  I suspect that you might be injecting the full container into your controllers instead of a service locator?  That used to work when twig was a public service but twig is now a private service.

Comment: Result of `bin/console debug:container HomeController`:

  Option           Value
  Service ID       App\Controller\HomeController
  Class            App\Controller\HomeController
  Tags             controller.service_arguments
                   container.service_subscriber
  Calls            setContainer
  Public           yes
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes

Comment: You really want to update your question when you add additional information.  Partly because comments don't format well but mainly because the question should be self contained.

Comment: In any event I suspect the problem is how your controller services are being defined.  Perhaps you transitioned from the base Controller class to the AbstractController class and did not get everything configured correctly.  Consider creating a new Symfony 6 project and adding a controller with `make:controller`. That should give you a simple working example of using twig that you can then use as a comparison.

Comment: I got similar problem with another service. The problem of the notice appeared because my service was private and automatically removed after migration. So I advise you to check the service declaration and check the recipe is up to date (composer recipe).

Comment: I tried many things to find the source, and have not found anything to unlock my situation yet. I updated the post with all information I found, but I'll stop searching for now. I'll come back to it later.

Comment: I have the same issue. For now I worked around it by injecting twig as a parameter in the service definition of the Controller. Somewhere the container configuration must be changed between Symfony 4 and 6. We upgraded from 4.4 to 5.4 and now 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I got a similar problem and found a solution by injecting `Psr\Container\ContainerInterface` instead of `service_container` in my "controller as a service" definition :

```
My\CustomBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments', 'container.service_subscriber']
    public: true
    calls:
        -   method: setContainer
            arguments: ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']
```

Solution found thanks to this github discussion : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/44628